# Prove that this language is not regular

Tags: regular-language

I need to prove that the language
$$L = \{a^nb^mc^k|n+k\neq3m\}$$

is not regular. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Have you tried pumping lemma?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use it in this particular example, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Ok, maybe the pumping lemma isn't the way to go directly in this case. Seems a bit tricky. What about closure properties of regular languages. If you had equality in the definition of $L$, it would be easy... OK now I think I see how to solve it. Do you want me to post a solution or is hint enough?

Comment: I'd prefer the solution as I don't think I can come up with it on my own.

Comment: OK. I actually had some already typed so I don't have to waste it :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume to the contrary that $L$ is regular. Then its complement $L^C$ is also regular. Now the language $A=\{a^ib^jc^k | i,j,k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is clearly regular. (Automaton: first take $a$'s, then $b$'s then $c$'s) So we have that the language

$$L^C\cap A = \{a^nb^mc^k | n+k=3m\}$$

is regular. But this, I think, can be seen not to be regular (with the pumping lemma).

To see that "the language with equality sign" isn't regular: If it has pumping length $p$, take the word $a^pb^pc^{2p}$. The pumping part must be contained in the $a^p$ part, so it's just $a^t$ for some $t$. Pump it to break the equality.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I believe I solved it!

Comment: Why $L^C \neq  \{a^nb^mc^k|n+k=3m\}$ ?

Comment: @user220688 Because there are words where the letters aren't in the order $a^nb^mc^k$, for example $ba \in L^C$.